# Getting a error when we use "pip3 install awscli" command

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, bash, pip, aws-cli

I am getting an eror as follows when I use pip3 install awscli. It was working fine earlier. It would be great if someone could help with this issue.

> Collecting awscli   Downloading awscli-1.29.3-py3-none-any.whl (4.1
> MB) Collecting s3transfer<0.7.0,>=0.6.0   Downloading
> s3transfer-0.6.1-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB) Collecting rsa<4.8,>=3.1.2
> Downloading rsa-4.7.2-py3-none-any.whl (34 kB) Collecting
> PyYAML<5.5,>=3.10   Downloading PyYAML-5.4.1.tar.gz (175 kB)
> Installing build dependencies: started   Installing build
> dependencies: finished with status 'done'   Getting requirements to
> build wheel: started   Getting requirements to build wheel: finished
> with status 'error'   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> command: /usr/bin/python3
> /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pep517/_in_process.py
> get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpvjbfu4r6

```
test:
  image:
    name: docker:stable
  
  before_script:
  - apk update
  - apk add curl py-pip jq bash
  - pip3 install awscli
```

Comment: Can you not use the [current AWS CLI install](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html)?  V1 is a bit old by now.

Comment: Thank you so much !! .Let me try it with new V2.

Comment: `asdf` tool is a good idea.

Comment: see https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/issues/601

Answer (score 0):

Same here, seems like you can't install awscli that way any longer.  The fix for me was to just install using apk.  You may be able to take the py-pip install out too.

```
test:
  image:
    name: docker:stable
  
  before_script:
  - apk update
  - apk add curl py-pip jq bash aws-cli
```